# Mathematically Describing Auto-unraveling systems

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, rotational-dynamics, integration, differential-equations

I am trying to mathematically describe the motion of a *auto-unravelling system*: **systems comprised a material (string, chain, cloth etc.) wound around a cylinder and left to unwind under the weight of the hanging segment of the material.**  I've tried two methods, each beginning with the angular form of Newton's second law, and each failing to accurately describe empirical results.

The graphs of empirical data are as shown in the following Desmos graphs:
Green Series: Angular Displacement, Red Series: Angular Velocity, Purple Series: Angular Acceleration. ***This applies to all graphs.***
[image: Green Series: Angular Displacement, Red Series: Angular Velocity, Purple Series: Angular Acceleration]

***Method 1***
[image: Newly formulated equation]

*Question: Did I make any mathematical errors in the derivations?*  Note: I used SymboLab to calculate the second order differential equation.

Comment: site policy on "check my work" questions https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6093/should-any-check-my-work-questions-be-made-on-topic

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Honestly, looking at your derivations is giving me a headache (why so many variables for such a simple situation?), but I have this piece of advice:

There is no need to even use the moment of inertia, because all of the chain, both on and off the spool, is always traveling at the same speed.  So the kinetic energy of the system is just $mv^2/2$, where $m$ is the total mass of the chain and $v=\omega*r$.

All that is left for you is to write the gravitational potential energy in terms of $L$ (the hanging length), solve for $v$ in terms of $L$, and integrate $dL/v$ to get an equation for the time elapsed in terms of the hanging length.  You can then solve for whatever you want in terms of time.

Comment: when you say that "all of the chain, both on and off the spool, is always travelling at the same speed"do you mean that the speed of the doesn't change (which I doubt due to acceleration) or that every point in the chain is moving at the same speed (since they're connected).  I'm guessing you mean the latter but I want to be sure.

Comment: sorry, i'm still lost, could you pls further explain w/o giving me the answer.  Where I am right now 

E(potential) = mgh = **g(mu)(l^2)/2** (h = l/2 as average of bead locations on hanging segment).

E(kinetic) = m(v^2)/2 =
 **(mu)(l)(v^2)/2** ?  If you equate then you get **gl = v^2**.  What is this integration step you speak of?

Comment: NOTE: mu is mass per 1 meter of chain

Comment: Oh dear.  Reverse the sign and your gravitational potential looks okay. For the kinetic energy you need the mass of the whole length of chain, not just the hanging bit.  The integration is literally what I said, you put an integral sign in front of the expression I typed and evaluate it, setting t=0 at l=l_0.  Basically that integral is adding up the time it takes to move each little bit of length, which we call "dL" in the integral.

Comment: sorry for bothering you (but thanks for the help so far) I have two questions:
I am familiar with integration (We did it a lot in ib math) but we barely use in physics --> **could you pls send me some resources on how to apply integration to physics problems**.  2. when you say integrate dL/v **did you mean dL/dV?**

Comment: I meant what I said.  As far as resources, I just learned from my classes, so I'm not sure where to send you. Try googling advanced mechanics practice problems with solutions?

Comment: I guess i'll have to wait till uni but until then I've made edits to the questions (hopefully it isn't headache inducing like the last one).  I'm still struggling with the integration bit ):  Note that *lh* is const since the chain starts off touching the ground.   I'm really unfamiliar with integration like the one you proposed (I've only ever integrated values of tiny intervals of distance (dx) or tiny intervals of time (dt) never velocity (v) )

Comment: NVM I'VE GOT SOMETHING tysm!

Comment: nvm it didn't work (it didn't match with empirical data)